# How can i get the complete tree view of entire sharepoint documents just like site map or explorer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

Now here's the case, i just recently joined a company with the task of PMO have been assigned the task to clean up the companies sharepoint user portal. With almost anything and everything been uploaded in the sharepoint by the developers (as the evidence of the meeting etc.) the documents are no more needed after specific period of time.

Since there are exhaustive list of documents that needs to be gone through. its little difficult to keep the note of the documents which are to be removed (remember im preparing the note of document to be removed and get the approval and then the archiving would happen)

So for this i just need to get the tree view of the entire documents structure(hierarchy) so, i could take a printout of the view and could give the appropriate note against it.

The point here is been the user im not quite sure wether that feature is available in sharepoint or do we have to get in touch with the company's  sharepoint dev team.

Answer (score 0):

I think a close result to what you are asking is by having Visio professional (not sure if visio standard has it) and use the Website map
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxVRl.jpg

obviously you will get a lot of default server file and libraries that are not of your interest but that is the closest you can get. Not sure if the representation of files within folders is optimal.

Otherwise the solution is very manual and you can use the page Content and Structure (see in site settings in any top level site collection for Content and structure). This page/view cannot be exported.

The other manual action is to export in excel the content of every document library which will also export the author of the document and timestamps. The button is 'Open in excel'.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to one of the migration tools like ShareGate og Metalogixs then you should be able to extract a listing of the files. Otherwise a PowerShell script like this might be an option : https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Get-a-list-of-all-files-on-a7f8719c

Answer (score -1):

I figured out exactly how to do this, and it's very easy. Check out my article on LinkedIn:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-export-sharepoint-document-library-excel-show-folder-cardonick